# Probability that people are chosen in different groups?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Let's say that I have $n$ people and $m \le n$ of this people are malicious. Then I run a process that chooses 6 people randomly and assigns each of them to one of two different groups $A$ and $B$ such that each group in the end has 3 people. What is the probability that there will be at least a malicious person in every group?

I have already asked help with this question but I am not sure about the correctness of the answers

[What is the probability that some people are chosen in different groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653421/what-is-the-probability-that-some-people-are-chosen-in-different-groups)

I modified one of the proposed answers in this way.

So I need to calculate the complement of "Events where at least a group has no bad people"

so the number of ways in which I can choose 6 people and divide them in groups of 3 is:
$$ {n\choose 6} {6\choose 3}$$

The events where a group has no bad people:

$${n-m\choose 6}{6\choose 3}$$

events where only a single person is malicious:

$$ {m\choose 1} {n-m\choose 5} {6\choose 3}$$

events where 2 people are malicious and in the same group

$$ {m\choose 2} {n-m\choose 4} {4\choose 3} 4$$

events where 3 people are bad and in the same group

$$ {m\choose 3}{n-m\choose 3}{3\choose 3} $$

so the total probability of my question is:

$$
P = 1 - \frac{{n-m\choose 6}{6\choose 3}+{m\choose 1} {n-m\choose 5} {6\choose 3}+{m\choose 2} {n-m\choose 4} {4\choose 3} 4+{m\choose 3}{n-m\choose 3}{3\choose 3}}{{n\choose 6} {6\choose 3}}
$$

Is my method correct?

Comment: It may be easier to find the probability that all of the malicious people are in a single group.